# can't install gRain package

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I am new to R and trying to install the gRain package. However, I am getting the error:

```
 dependency ‘gRbase’ is not available
```

Then, when trying to install gRbase I get:

```
package ‘gRbase’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it requires R 3.6.0 or higher. At least that is what the docs [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRbase/index.html) say.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies `graph`, `RBGL` and `Rgraphviz` are not on CRAN but on [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/).

To install these packages, execute

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
bioLite(c("graph", "RBGL", "Rgraphviz"))
```

Then install the packages from CRAN in the usual way:

```
install.packages("gRain", dependencies=TRUE)
```

See also the [`gRain` installation instructions](http://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/software/gR/).

Comment: bioconductor should be used anymore, apparently now biocmanager shall be used, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiocManager/vignettes/BiocManager.html

Comment: it only worked after I did:  line 1)  install.packages("BiocManager")

line 2)         BiocManager::install(c("RBGL"))